# Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI code

Tags: blockchain, solidity, verify, contract, etherscan

Compiler debug log:
**Error! Unable to generate Contract Bytecode and ABI**
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : mycontractname
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVvSj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ohYy.png)

all things are matched.

and **Optimization:true;**

Comment: You need to provide more context, what is the configuration you compiled with and deployed?